# Insert a character in a filename, depending on filename length

Tags: rename, sort

I've got about 18k of files which are named this way:

```
0001_6548
0002_7674
...
14767_4536
```

I need to add a leading zero to filenames that contain only 4 digits in the first part, so they naturally sort the right way.

Comment: To get exact results, please elaborate a little

Comment: I can't understand exactly what your filenames are or what you want them to be. Please could you [edit] your question and give some samples of what you have (a couple you want to rename, and and couple you do not want to rename) and the results you want from those (show the same samples, some renamed and some not, as you want)

Comment: What to do with files without `_`, use basename for lenght? ARe there possibly directories in the directory?

Answer (score 3):

Easy job for `rename` (`prename`), from that directory:

```
rename -n 's/^\d{4}_\d{4}$/0$&/' [[:digit:]]*
```

Drop `-n` for actual action.

- `^\d{4}_\d{4}$` matches filenames with 4 digits followed by a `_`, then again 4 digits
- Those files are renamed with a `0` prefixed, `0$&`

**Example:**

```
% ls [[:digit:]]*
0001_6548  0002_7674  14767_4536

% rename -n 's/^\d{4}_\d{4}$/0$&/' [[:digit:]]*
0001_6548 renamed as 00001_6548
0002_7674 renamed as 00002_7674

% rename 's/^\d{4}_\d{4}$/0$&/' [[:digit:]]* 

% ls [[:digit:]]*                              
00001_6548  00002_7674  14767_4536
```

Comment: It's Centos i got here on workstation and it doesnt support Perl. Any ideas of how make it with rename.ul ( i believe it is the same to centos rename)

Comment: You mean you are asking a CentOS related question in AskUbuntu website? Then this is an OFF-TOPIC

Comment: Refer to this: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/5lim1i/cent7_how_to_get_perl_version_of_rename/?st=j10gddoe&sh=ef8b266e  You'll have to install cpan and then obtain perl rename utility. On Ubuntu , `prename` is installed by default and heemayl's is absolutely proper answer. But again - please don't assume that "just because it's Linux" you can ask questions anywhere. Ubuntu has specific set of tools distinct form CentOS

Comment: I got that. Will drop my question there. I doubt my root uses python, but if it is so i'll try your script tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install krename
```

It's a good gui based application for batch file renaming. Try it out

[How To Batch Rename Files in Ubuntu with KRename](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/04/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-ubuntu-with-krename.html?m=1)

This article explains how to use krename (I'm not the author)

Answer (score 0):

Python solution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import listdir,path,rename
from sys import argv
import re
for i in listdir("."):
    if i == argv[0] or not path.isfile(i):
        continue
    if re.match('\d{4}_\d{4}',i):
        rename(i,'0'+i)
```

Test:

```
$ ls
0001_6548  0002_7674  14767_4536  append_zero.py*
$ ./append_zero.py                                    
$ ls
00001_6548  00002_7674  14767_4536  append_zero.py*
```